# Packed Chrome extension alarms not going off at scheduled time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I was developing my Chrome extension I used the alarms API, and it worked without any issues. After uploading it to the Chrome Web Store, it doesn't trigger at the scheduled times (I am settings timers greater than one minute). I tested with a 5 minute timer, and it took 5 minutes and 47 seconds to trigger. I am considering switching to setting a timeout for the timers, but would prefer to use the alarms API. Below is a screenshot of the scheduled time going over the actual time.

[image: Chrome alarms API not triggering at scheduled time]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The documentation of the alarms API says alarms can be delayed arbitrarily in the "production mode".

Comment: @wOxxOm, is >30 seconds considered an arbitrary amount? I thought it would be a few seconds at most of a delay, is there any range of the delay?

Comment: Arbitrary means there's no range, otherwise it'd be mentioned.